# ios create and then dynamically add UI elements

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, reusability

I don't know if this is possible but it sounds like something that should be.

What i want to do is, to create UIViews (or UIViewControllers not really sure how it would work) in Interface Builder say... 10 of them, and use them according to what the user choose to.

For example in state A i wanna show him widgets 1,2 and 3;
in state B widgets 3,5 and 7 etc.

EDIT: what i mean by state, is that according to what the user chose in the previous steps, they all lead to the same UIViewController but it should present itself differently according to the aforementioned "state". And now I can't create a different UIViewController for every different combination :)

And also being able to position them in the parent view is a must.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so in answer to your comment, you can indeed do just what you want. Create a separate nib file for your custom view, say MyView.xib, and make the File's Owner's class to be whatever your view controller class is.

Then in your view controller, create an `IBOutlet` property for the custom view:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet MyView * myView;
```

In the nib file, hook up the `myView` outlet of the view controller, to the top level view.

Then to load the view in code, all you need to do is:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] )loadNibNamed: @"MyView" owner: self options: nil];
```

and the nib will be loaded, and assigned to `myView`. Then you can add it as a subview.

To make this work with another view controller, just make sure it has the same named outlet, make the `loadNibNamed:` call, and it will just work.

Comment: Ideally, i want to create all the UIView widgets in one or multiple XIBs and alloc-initwithFrame them according to the state of the app and add them to the superview.

Comment: To give you an idea: I have a UITableView sequense that eventually leads to the UIViewController i am talking about. now according to the choices the user made in those UITableViewControllers, i want to present a different "state". As in, different combination of "widgets".

Comment: and a big fat green check for you sir!

Comment: not that i need it right now, but how would i go about adding that "external" view to yet *another* view controller? Or is that taking it too far? :p

Comment: As long as the other view controller has the same named outlet, just make the loadNibNamed: call, and it will just work.

Comment: yeah but the File's Owner will be the first view controller we discussed, how will i make the connection to the outlet? :o - Merry Xmas too! :)

Comment: It happens "automagically", as long as the outlet in the 2nd view controller is named the same. Think of the outlet as coming from File's Owner, irrespective of its class. Then whichever class loads the NIB file (i.e. its owner) will have its outlets assigned just as you hooked them up.