# How to create and use reusable view-templates

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiview, subviews

I'm new to iOS development and standing in front of some kind of Problem:

I need something like a view-template which i could load and fill multiple times inside another view.

For Example:
The view-template exists of:

UILabel
UIImageView    UILabel    UIButton

In my App i want to load it dynamicaly and multiple times:

```
[myAppView]

UILabel
Something...
Something...

view-template (with added content)
view-template (with added content)
view-template (with added content)
view-template (with added content)
view-template (with added content)

Something...

[/myAppView]
```

How can i do that?
Is that and usefull start: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616053/ios-create-and-then-dynamically-add-ui-elements)?

Comment: one view template and you want to display it as many different screen? is that it?

Comment: This is what .xibs and custom views are for.

Comment: @sunajledif no, i want to display it multiple times on one screen

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: i use now custom table cells with subviews as templates - i think that works best for my goal

Comment: So, then you are asking how to create a custom UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds like your goal, then, is to create a custom `UITableViewCell` which you populate with model data.

There are many opinions and options for doing this, depending on the complexity of your design, number of rows in the `UITableView` and other consideration.

Check out some tutorials on custom `UITableViewCell`.  Like [this](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/), or [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html)